Are Hecke L-functions associated to Artin L-functions primitive?
I'm reading a famous paper by Lagarias & Odlyzko on effective versions of the Chebotarev density theorem. There is one thing about Artin L-functions that is a little perplexing to me.
Let $L/K$ be an abelian Galois extension of number fields with $G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$. Wikipedia says that for every irreducible character $\chi$ of $G$ (necessarily 1-dimensional), there exists a Hecke character $\chi'$ of $K$ such that
$$
L(s,\chi,L/K)=L(s,\chi'),
$$
where the LHS is the Artin L-function of $L/K$, and the RHS is the Hecke L-function.
My question is: Is it true that $\chi'$ is always primitive? Why or why not?
I'm asking this question for the following reason. In section 5 of the paper linked above, the author considered the irreducible characters $\chi$ of a cyclic subgroup $H\subset G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ and the associated Artin L-functions, which then correspond to Hecke L-functions by the above discussion. In equation (5.6), the author wrote down the functional equation for these Hecke L-functions, which however is only proved for primitive Hecke characters. Are they implicitly assuming that these Hecke L-functions associated to Artin L-functions are primitive?
I'm relatively new to class field theory and the world of L-functions (other than Dirichlet L-functions). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

What is the $E$ you mention ("Hecke character of $E$")?  The whole "primitivity" business is an artifact of using the original awkward definition of Hecke characters. If you use their definition in terms of ideles then that concept simply never arises because every primitive character and its imprimitive lifts get identified with one and the same Hecke character using ideles.

@KCd Sorry, that was a typo. It should have been "Hecke character of
." So is the answer to the question affirmative? I'm worried about primitivity because I want to write down functional equations for these Hecke L-functions (associated to the irreducible characters of an abelian Galois group).

Yes. When you use an imprimitive Hecke character, its $L$-function may be missing some Euler factors that are needed in a nice functional equation. This already occurs with $L$-functions of Dirichlet characters.  When $\chi_4$ is the nontrivial character mod $4$, it is primitive, its lifting to a character $\chi$ modulo $12$ is imprimitive, and $L(s,\chi)$ equals $L(s,\chi_4)$ with the Euler factor at $3$ missing.

@KCd Thanks, that makes sense. Do you have any reference for the fact that those Hecke L-functions associated to the irreducible characters are always primitive?

Off the top of my head I can't give you a reference.  Did you try taking a proof in the case of Dirichlet $L$-functions and try to extend it to Hecke character $L$-functions? Or probably if you use the idelic definition of a Hecke character and its $L$-function and then translate the definition into the more classical description of Hecke characters that you're using, you'll see the $L$-function belongs to a primitive Hecke character.
